# how to write the where clause in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to write a Stored procedure with parameter,
I want to write a SQL that find HK order and the CN order

Here is an example like that
In user column, User A is HK User, User B is CN user
In region, CN is China, CS is cross border and HK is Hong Kong

```
user  orderno  region
A       1        cn
A       2        cs
A       3        hk
B       4        cn
B       5        cs
B       6        hk
```

For example I want to find the HK order that include the Cross Border with HK user create
And the result is to 2,3 and 6

```
user  orderno  region
A       2        cs
A       3        hk
B       6        hk
```

How to I write this where clause,Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure? Which dbms are you using (stored procedures are usually product specific.) What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt!

Comment: Why is record 5 not being included?

Comment: Because record 5 is create BY CN USER, I want to find HK order

Comment: I update mu stored procedure, And please help me to fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Ad don't know your database and parameter type here is only the concept

```
where user="A" and (region in ("cs","hk"))

or

where user="A" and (region="cs" or region="hk")
```

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, e.g. `"Odd column name"`. Use single quotes for string literals, e.g. `'some text'`.

Comment: I write my Stored procedure now, please read and help me to fixed,thanks